# CreatedAtRoute - No route matches the supplied values. (passing Parent/child values)

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

First, I have searched here for a similar situation to mine but have yet to find it.

I am trying to Create a company (child) that has a Tenant (parent) and return the URI value in the response.

**API controller route Setup**

```cs
[ApiController]
[Route("api/tenants/{tenantId}/companies")]
public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
```

**GetCompanyById Setup**

```cs
[HttpGet("{companyId:guid}")]
[ActionName(nameof(GetCompany))]
public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompany(Guid tenantId, Guid companyId)
{
    var result = await _sender.Send(new GetCompanyQuery(tenantId, companyId));

    return Ok(result);
}
```

**Create Method**

```cs
[HttpPost]
public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCompany(Guid tenantId, CreateCompanyRequest request)
{
    var company = new CreateCompanyCommand(
        request.Name,
        request.NavraeName,
        request.NavraeStoreNo,
        request.AddressStreet,
        request.AddressUnit,
        request.AddressCity,
        request.AddressState,
        request.AddressZip,
        request.Phone,
        request.Email,
        tenantId);

    var result = await _sender.Send(company);

    if (result.IsFailure)
        return BadRequest(result.Error);

    return CreatedAtRoute(
        routeName: nameof(GetCompany),
        routeValues: new {tenantId, companyId = result.Value}, 
        value: result);
}
```

I have tried using CreatedAtAction but get the following error:
[image: CreateAtActionError]

Comment: could you pls take a try to use `[HttpGet("{companyId:guid}", Name = "GetCompany")]` instead? And pls correct me if I misunderstood your issue...

Comment: Perfect! I assume defining the name inside the Verb call is where the CreateAtRoute is looking for the routeName. Thanks for the help :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't reproduced your issue but I have a test with code below and it worked well.

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebApi.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/tenants/{tenantId}/companies")]
    [ApiController]
    public class CompanyController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet("{companyId:guid}", Name = "GetCompany")]
        //[ActionName(nameof(GetCompany))]
        public async Task<IActionResult> GetCompany(Guid tenantId, Guid companyId)
        {
            return Ok();
        }
        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<IActionResult> CreateCompany(Guid tenantId)//, CreateCompanyRequest request
        {
            return CreatedAtRoute(
                routeName: nameof(GetCompany),
                routeValues: new { tenantId, companyId = Guid.NewGuid() },
                value: null);
        }
    }
}
```

[image]

And if I used

```
[HttpGet("{companyId:guid}")]
[ActionName(nameof(GetCompany))]
```

I would get 500 error.

[image]